# Adding a self-referential field

Tags: drupal

I am creating a new content type called `idhhb_node`. This content type represents any of the training material available through a company - books, cds, websites, etc. An `idhhb_node` will have between 1 and 5 prerequisites.

The problem is the prerequisites are also of type `idhhb_node`, but the pulldown for field type does not allow `List(iddhb_node)` as a type.

Another interesting thing. It appears that the pre-existing node types are not available as fields either. For instance, a field cannot be an `Article` or `Page` even though Drupal 7 comes with those nodes activated by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, which gives you access to an Entity Reference field type. It allows you to do more than the standard Node Reference fields.